# Exclude column from result CrudRepository findOne method

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

I need to exclude a large column from result of `findAll` method from `CrudRepository` to speed up a response from database.

How I can to that? Is it a `@Query` a only way to do that?

Current `findAll` SQL query:

```
select f.id, f.name, f.largeColumn from foo f
```

My target:

```
select f.id, f.name from foo f
```

I'm using `spring-data-jpa`

My working attempt using a `@NamedQuery` (any simplier version?)

**Foo.java**

```
@NamedQueries(value = {
    @NamedQuery(name = Foo.QUERY_FIND_ALL_NO_XML, query = "select f.id, f.name from Foo f")
})
//...
public static final String QUERY_FIND_ALL_NO_XML = "Foo.findAllNoXml";
```

**FooDao.java**

```
public Iterable<Foo> findAllNoXml();
```